# Ubuntu:which folder in ubuntu like windows "program files"?I asking that because i want to know where put 3 party programs

Tags: ubuntu

which folder in ubuntu like windows "program files"?I asking that because i want to know where put 3 party programs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linux (and Ubuntu, being just another Linux distribution) have a different folder hierarchy than Windows. There is no exact matching to “Program Files”, although ‘/usr/bin’ is a fairly close.

In general, you would like to put your binaries in /usr/bin (unless your program is “essential”, in which case you’ll put it in ‘/bin’). Note that typically you will not create a dedicated folder for your application, but /usr/bin is a huge folder with all executable of all programs.

The configuration files of your program will go to /etc or /etc/your_program, and if you have any state information put it in ‘/var/lib’.

Beleive it or not, this is all defined in a standard called **FHS** (Filesystem Hierarchy Standard). Find more details here:

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)

Answer (score 4):

/usr/local or /opt/

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use dedicated folder / or /usr/local/ or /opt/ as mentioned change vendor to the name o 3rd party or product name). After that You should configure environment variables ( PATH) in .profile for example. It is worth of effort because during update You will have easier control what parts of the system You are modifying.

Answer (score 3):

Windows is not Linux.

Typing

```
man hier
```

in a Linux console and reading that is a good starting point.